# Changing tables datatype from varchar to text PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a problem and search for a solution on Google but can't find any. I have a postgres table with name `products_199` and in that table there's a column with name `parameter2` type `varchar (255)`. I want to change the datatype to `text` but somehow I get the following error

> ERROR:  parser: parse error at or near "TYPE" at character 50

My command looks like follows that I want to execute

```
ALTER TABLE products_199 ALTER COLUMN parameter2 TYPE text;
```

I'm using  PostgreSQL 7.3.4

Comment: You really should upgrade. 7.3 is no longer supported - it was released 6 years ago.
The oldest supported version is 8.0, but I don't see any reason not to upgrade to 8.4 or even 8.3

Comment: Yes I would, the reason why I did not do so yet is, there are 4000+ sites running on the server from the pg database, I don't want to have any downtime by messing up the db

Comment: You should at least upgrade to the latest available version in the 7.3 series, which is 7.3.21. It should have bugfixes only over 7.3.4, and no behavioral changes. It's still not supported, but it's an improvement.

Comment: I'm planning to upgrade to the newest version l

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* that syntax is only available in newer PostgreSQL versions.

If you can't change versions (7.3.4 is quite old), i suggest you just add a new column, copy over the data, and drop the old column. That would be the safest way imo.

Something like this (not tested, backup first!)

```
begin; 
alter table products_199 add column parameter2_n text; 
update products_199 set parameter2_n=parameter2; 
alter table products_199 drop column parameter2;
commit;
vacuum;
```